# Web-scraper process

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been trying to replace some text in my output but i've had no luck.

I want the output to look something like this

```
su-n-s-e-t
 https://64.media.tumblr.com/35fb46ace19cf31bf16c3655eff26fa6/bc3cfd4a41299b1e-9a/s500x750/98bbd40e71066761a4bd5983896932dd56c94427.jpg
houndsofvalinor-art
 https://64.media.tumblr.com/e89e2a223d965a0351e310c829389583/ce52b6a3e76c58be-6e/s500x750/43548527d68eac8def536a88901a2ff78355ef51.jpg 
amazinglybeautifulphotography
 https://64.media.tumblr.com/a7d31eb63666d39d10868debbab9e27c/5be73c7f5dadb3dd-aa/s500x750/5b10d9cc0400e7b0dbabb9ea14c37e6b91e85e91.jpg 
kylebonallo
 https://64.media.tumblr.com/b406c3ceb50e4e09e550710b35de1310/dddef868163205f7-71/s500x750/9fec23368ed8ca5d6effae89fbdcda54554d0a68.jpg 
expressions-of-nature
 https://64.media.tumblr.com/e1eb3612511e21177dfa66ac02f07b98/c5b5c1fc2cbbc58d-e1/s500x750/550dbdf7568167891c5ea1af18af9cbc91cd620f.jpg 
ex0skeletal-undead
 https://64.media.tumblr.com/14d837eb6159b8376443393d8b1ef551/fb5d595667e75d0f-79/s500x750/cee48e58e0b1191376e20fd11904c09adbea50b3.jpg 
geopsych
 https://64.media.tumblr.com/a596b92db62c8ae4f68b490d172f8227/c856f013961ced0e-10/s500x750/73fb838c8065174e5ede5d93698ea386e6df1efe.jpg 
jacobvanloon
 https://64.media.tumblr.com/ca5f1e13bb4642de55422e74611f1df6/6f85f80cb48e73f7-e4/s500x750/12b59223056baf7733d99f210f1cd8bc397d52cd.png 
amazinglybeautifulphotography
 https://64.media.tumblr.com/06a1ff4abc50e80df59ddbd6e9c8c42c/3fd49bbbfb9dffd8-df/s500x750/43d3adf64f6fec58ebd37633be4988f36746e819.jpg
```

The `url_list` variable returns:

```
geopsych
[' https://64.media.tumblr.com/a596b92db62c8ae4f68b490d172f8227/c856f013961ced0e-10/s500x750/73fb838c8065174e5ede5d93698ea386e6df1efe.jpg 500w']
burningmine
[' https://64.media.tumblr.com/e32b99ad1de8f8cd494205982c0137a1/54985812c55123d3-99/s500x750/cbe83b505eb14ff36e2be05e171a30bfd073a41b.jpg 500w']
amazinglybeautifulphotography
[' https://64.media.tumblr.com/06a1ff4abc50e80df59ddbd6e9c8c42c/3fd49bbbfb9dffd8-df/s500x750/43d3adf64f6fec58ebd37633be4988f36746e819.jpg 500w']
```

This is what I have tried:

```
for results in urls:
                results.replace('500w','')
```

but I still get it with `500w` on the end.

And since I want to get every link in a single line without the `['']` I tried to split it with `.split('\n')`, instead of `.split(',')` but it seems i get an error too when I use that.

Here is the rest of the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_term = 'landscape'
posts_scrape = requests.get(f'https://www.tumblr.com/search/{search_term}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(posts_scrape.text, 'html.parser')

articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='_2DpMA')

for article in articles:
    try:
        source = article.find('div', class_='_3QBiZ').text
        urls = []
        for imgvar in article.find_all('img', alt='Image'):
            url_list = [i for i in imgvar['srcset'].split(',') if (i.find('500w') != -1)]
            urls.append(url_list)
        for results in urls:
            results.replace('500w','')
        print (source)
        print (results)
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

Comment: What is the content of the `url_list` variable after your loop? You have provided the desired output but not the input or the output you're actually getting

Comment: True, I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use dictionary to store image URLS. The keys are source of the image and values are lists of image URLs. For example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_term = "landscape"
posts_scrape = requests.get(f"https://www.tumblr.com/search/{search_term}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(posts_scrape.text, "html.parser")

articles = soup.find_all("article", class_="_2DpMA")

data = {}
for article in articles:
    try:
        source = article.find("div", class_="_3QBiZ").text
        for imgvar in article.find_all("img", alt="Image"):
            data.setdefault(source, []).extend(
                [
                    i.replace("500w", "").strip()
                    for i in imgvar["srcset"].split(",")
                    if "500w" in i
                ]
            )
    except AttributeError:
        continue

for source, image_urls in data.items():
    for url in image_urls:
        print(source)
        print(url)
```

Prints:

```
leahberman
https://64.media.tumblr.com/e29c3dd39ab0e413ff6eefa0cfc973de/d6817667d3007f74-09/s500x750/2971fc9af6619f1f783bb169b104dea023f339de.gifv
leahberman
https://64.media.tumblr.com/8c61e084290ccea6fef3eab1d96204fd/d6817667d3007f74-b8/s500x750/45873681924618d179bfc97e04a02d3d6ebaac39.gifv
leahberman
https://64.media.tumblr.com/c4db8bc21289aec008219f5a4b307714/d6817667d3007f74-85/s500x750/c49d38c369ccb507d950b116e637886ac4467685.gifv
poetry-siir
https://64.media.tumblr.com/5495c24e4608688a6a0052d81da01882/d97a76eeb3edd5e9-d7/s500x750/9862a63fe430e83850ceb73f384bf2af6322db5e.jpg
poetry-siir
https://64.media.tumblr.com/9944d7a5d2d26a57118c8b391b699efb/d97a76eeb3edd5e9-ad/s500x750/7cfc69a18143d5b2a678fe0c85c431e5387a2107.jpg

...and so on.
```

Comment: This is actually a perfect answer and what I was looking for, thank you so much I really apreciate the reply!! Will keep on investigating about this on my own since I am learning python on my own, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue lies mostly within this line of code:

```
results.replace('500w','')
```

First: `results` is a list, so it doesn't have a `.replace()` method. You would see that if you did not silence the `AttributeError`. You should at least print an error this way:

```
except AttributeError as exc:
    print(exc)
```

and you would see it outputs a very descriptive error: `'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`

Second: I guess you want to replace the actual urls within `results` to remove the '500w' at the end.  Strings in Python are immutable, which means that any transformation to a `str` will create a new `str` instead of modifying the first one. So here you are modifying a `str`, creating a new one but not storing it anywhere.

Third: your `urls` list is erased at every iteration of the `for` loop. You probably want to declare it outside the loop and have it contain all matching urls.

Here is a code which does what I understand you want to do:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_term = 'landscape'
posts_scrape = requests.get(f'https://www.tumblr.com/search/{search_term}')
soup = BeautifulSoup(posts_scrape.text, 'html.parser')

articles = soup.find_all('article', class_='_2DpMA')

urls = []

for article in articles:
    try:
        source = article.find('div', class_='_3QBiZ').text
        for imgvar in article.find_all('img', alt='Image'):
            url = next((i for i in imgvar['srcset'].split(',') if i.endswith('500w')), None)
            if url:
                urls.append(url.strip().replace(' 500w', ''))
    except AttributeError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Comment: This is big learning for me thank you so much!!